# display:table-cell behaving differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm built a graph in Chrome which looks like this: 
[image]

But in Firefox it looks like this:
[image]

I'm pretty sure the discrepancy is the result of `display:table-cell` getting handled differently in the two browsers. But I'm not sure how to fix it. I uploaded a live demo [here](http://streetofwalls.com/graph-dev/) so you can inspect the code.

Comment: Have you thought about using [tag:svg]? Unless you're worried about non-modern browsers, you're creating a lot of extra work using [tag:html].

Comment: `display:table; position: absolute` can't work; it's one or the other (it'll be `display:table` for browsers)

Comment: @BoltClock YES SIR! thanks for setting me straight about that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to fix it:

1. Apply `display: table-row` to `.graph`
2. Use `inline-block` instead of `table-cell` on `.series`
3. Avoid using crazy float number percentage ( like *14.2857%* ) because of the browsers' math engines that almost always do the rounding in different ways.

Comment: #3 is a great point. If you want to go a step further, you can define pixel-based lengths and do yourself and the browser a huge favor.

Comment: BOOM! Thanks, Zoltan. I totally spaced out on `display:table-row;`. Is there any harm in using small floats (like 13.5%) for widths, or are you suggesting no floats at all? I'm using all the percentages because the graph needs to be responsive. As it's currently set up, it should scale proportionally according to the container. Does that excuse the way I've done it, or is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: percentages are OK as long as they can't be treated diffidently by different browsers, so try to avoid anything that has a decimal part (e.g. 13.5%). However 14% is perfectly OK

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with relative positioning in firefox. Change the positioning of the .series and a few more changes, and it works. 
In firefox, the %width is actually calculating the percentage from outer division, because of the relative positioning.